# Unable to connect with internet on Kali Linux using dualboot

Tags: kali-linux, dualboot

I am trying to connect my laptop to mobile data using usb cable. It shows that it is connected , but when I am unable to run various sites on browser. When I am trying to ping google.com it's shows name or service not known

Comment: Check there Meta Q/A: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me    https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5257/why-are-kali-questions-hated-so-much

Comment: Try an Ethernet connection for the Kali machine to see if that works.